# Issue stripping the values of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of elements named 'files_temp':

```
['CDS_SPREAD_AA1EUNBCBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AA1EUNCCBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AA1USNBCBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AA1USNCCBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AALLN1EUNECBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AALLN1USNECBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_ABB3EUNECBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_ABB3USNECBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_ABX1EUNCCBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_ABX1USNCCBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_ACAFP1EUBECBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_ACAFP1EUNECBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_ACOM1JPNACBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_ACOM1USNACBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AEGON1EUBACBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AEGON1EUNECBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AEGON1JPBACBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AEGON1USBACBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AEGON1USNECBM', 'CDS_SPREAD_AEP1USNBCBM' ...]
```

I would like to keep only the alphanumeric codes, removing the `CDS_SPREAD_` part and tried the following code:

```
files_temp=[elem.strip('CDS_SPREAD_') for elem in files_temp]
```

However, besides the `CDS_SPREAD_` part it is also removing a part of the alphanumeric code:

```
['1EUNBCBM', '1EUNCCBM', '1USNBCBM', '1USNCCBM', 'LLN1EUNECBM', 'LLN1USNECBM', 'BB3EUNECBM', 'BB3USNECBM', 'BX1EUNCCBM', 'BX1USNCCBM', 'FP1EUBECBM', 'FP1EUNECBM', 'OM1JPNACBM', 'OM1USNACBM', 'GON1EUBACBM', 'GON1EUNECBM', 'GON1JPBACBM', 'GON1USBACBM', 'GON1USNECBM', '1USNBCBM', '1USNCCBM', 'T1EUNCCBM', 'T1USNBCBM' ...]
```

For instance, for the first element, in theory I should get `AA1EUNBCBM` instead of `1EUNBCBM`. Would you know why this is happening? I would highly appreciate an alternative to solve the issue as well.

Comment: Have you tried using `replace` method?

Comment: What about using `elem[len("CDS_SPREAD_"):]` (although not very efficient) instead of *strip*?

Answer (score 0):

The `strip()` function removes all the characters you are providing as the parameters. For your case, you should use `replace()` function.

```
files_temp=[elem.replace('CDS_SPREAD_', '') for elem in files_temp]
```